# python.connector.connect host is a network ip

Tags: python, mysql

today i'm working on a project and i thought maybe it's possible to write a python program that uses a database from a local / hosted based mysql server so i tried this code from w3schools

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  #host="192.168.10.200", <- tried this
  #host="tcp://192.168.10.200", <- also tried this
  host="localhost", #<- this works    
  user="web-server",
  passwd="yourpassword"
)

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")

for x in mycursor:
  print(x)
```

i tried it with the localhost and sure it brings up the databases in phpmyadmin, also for the 192.168.10.200 that's a centos server running httpd and mysql i did check via browser and confirmed that i can access both but when i try it on python it doesn't work any ideas? i'm really out of words and ideas to google some said port forwarding, public IP but i'd like to stay away from those if possible anyway hope you guys can help me.

Comment: What is the problem?  setting the IP to "localhost" or "127.0.0.1" works right?

Comment: yes localhost works fine, but i don't want localhost, i want it to be able to get the sql data from 192.168.10.200, it's on the other server

Comment: Do you have trouble opening phpMyAdmin or connecting to MySQL through Python? Your tags are misleading. phpMyAdmin is a MySQL administration tool written in PHP, it is not a database itself.

Comment: ah yeah sorry about that, i removed phpMyAdmin, anyway yes i sort of somehow have trouble connecting MySQL through python you see, the MySQL server i have is not within my xampp or local sql, it's on a centos server which still belongs to the same network but python just won't connect to it got any ideas?